# review my websites url system?

Tags: php, mysql, url, uri

i would like some expert people like yourselves with more experience, to review the way i am handling url for my website and share thoughts about stuff that what can be troubling in future or any security risks.

My url looks like following:

```
website.com/post.php?v=the-title-of-post-dateYear-dateMonth-dateDay-postID
```

when the users comes to this page, the logic in post.php cuts out the `postID` of the url and do mysql query and check if the post exists and flagged as public post.

let me tell you that i am abit unhappy that the `postID` revail the number of my items in my database as its a sequential ID. I know that can use base64 to encode and decode but it returns a random string of some letters that makes the url look ugly and might confuse the user. i am interested to convert the `postID` to a random number(the shorter the better), if you know anything like that , i would appreciate the tip.

Comment: Why not just do something like `v=thetitleofpost&d=date&pid=id`, instead?

Comment: you mean remove the dashes ? its there for SEO purposes

Comment: It will make your life ten times easier, and (in my opinion) it will look cleaner

Comment: @pabloBar If the parameters are after `?`, they already hurt SEO, so splitting them into separate parameters doesn't make it any worse.

Comment: Why is sequential IDs a problem? That's how it is on just about every site.

Comment: @Caelan. in which way ? when looking up a post in the database, i am just using the postID so it does not really matter if i have dashes or not ?

Comment: @Barmar. the only parameter in the url is the postID. Well the Sequential IDs are not really a problem, more like that i just dislike the idea of revails number of records in my database. if the last valid id is 90 then it says that i have 90 records in my database

Comment: Your URL also has `the-title-of-post-dateYear-dateMonth-dateDay` in the parameter.

Comment: Take a look at how SO's URLs look for a design that's good for SEO. You can use a rewrite rule to convert it to a form that's easier for PHP to process.

Comment: 1. If you do a simple string concentration (without sanitizing the input) in your PHP code it's likely that someone could inject a ' to break your query. Giving him the ability to execute random MySQL statements. So the question about security cannot be answered, as long as you do not show how you handle the MySQL part. 2. The SO URL might be good (if search engines put attention to it), but the drawback is that someone can cut off the description title and scrap all the content with increasing the question number. As for SO it's not a problem, but I've seen other sites with valuable content.